# Помогите доделать анимацию

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, анимация

Вот что у меня уже есть

```js
function animation(el) {
  el.target.classList.toggle('animation-flash')
  el.target.classList.toggle('menu__top--active')
  el.target.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('fa-arrow-left--active')
}
```

```css
.menu__top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  right: -250px;
  box-shadow: -27px 0 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
  transition: right .4s;
  z-index: 21;
  margin: 0;
  top: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__top>i {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  color: var(--color-gray);
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.menu__top__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background: var(--color-white-active);
}

.menu__top--active {
  right: 0;
}

.menu__top__content--title {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

.menu__top--link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 3px 0px;
  color: var(--color-black);
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.menu__top--link:hover {
  color: var(--color-black-active);
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animation-flash {
  animation: flash linear 2s infinite;
}

.fa-arrow-left--active {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="menu__top animation-flash" onmouseenter="animation(event)" onmouseleave="animation(event)">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>
  <div class="menu__top__content">
    <div class="menu__top__content--title">
      <span>Ссылки</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как видно меню выдвигается при наведение на стрелочку, а как сделать, чтоб меню выдвигалось при наведение на `div.menu__top`. Пробовал увелечить ширину (`width`) блока, но тогда было видно содержимое этого меню и белую полосу от `background`. Как это сделать? И как это можно получше сделать, это мигание стрелочки. Буду очень рад вашим советам.

Comment: Может сделать меню по умолчанию прозрачным и показывать :hover?

Comment: А вам нужно поправить ваш вариант? Или нормальный сделать с нуля?

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev Можно и поправить, но можно и с нуля) Буду не против

Comment: @Plikard Ну можно и так сделать, но я хочу, чтоб пользователь видел, что там что-то есть, чтоб он заглянул что там такое))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не править глобально, то используйте псевдоэлемент `:before` для основного контейнера, чтоб сделать невидимую накладку:

```js
function animation(el) {
  el.target.classList.toggle('animation-flash')
  el.target.classList.toggle('menu__top--active')
  el.target.firstElementChild.classList.toggle('fa-arrow-left--active')
}
```

```css
.menu__top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  right: -250px;
  box-shadow: -27px 0 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
  transition: right .4s;
  z-index: 21;
  margin: 0;
  top: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__top:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: transparent;
  width: 90px;
}

.menu__top>i {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  color: var(--color-gray);
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .2s ease;
  -webkit-animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
  animation: blink 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
50% { opacity: 1 }
51% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes blink { 
50% { opacity: 1 }
51% { opacity: 0 }
100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.menu__top__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background: var(--color-white-active);
}

.menu__top--active {
  right: 0;
}

.menu__top__content--title {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

.menu__top--link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 3px 0px;
  color: var(--color-black);
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.menu__top--link:hover {
  color: var(--color-black-active);
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animation-flash {
  animation: flash linear 2s infinite;
}

.fa-arrow-left--active {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="menu__top animation-flash" onmouseenter="animation(event)" onmouseleave="animation(event)">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>
  <div class="menu__top__content">
    <div class="menu__top__content--title">
      <span>Ссылки</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Убрал слушатели, все работает по `:hover`

```css
.menu__top {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
  right: -250px;
  box-shadow: -27px 0 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.098);
  transition: right .4s;
  z-index: 21;
  margin: 0;
  top: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__top>i {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30px;
  top: 50%;
  color: var(--color-gray);
  opacity: .8;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.menu__top__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  background: var(--color-white-active);
}

.menu__top--active {
  right: 0;
}

.menu__top__content--title {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
}

.menu__top--link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 3px 0px;
  color: var(--color-black);
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.menu__top--link:hover {
  color: var(--color-black-active);
}

@keyframes flash {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: .1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.animation-flash {
  animation: flash linear 2s infinite;
}

.fa-arrow-left--active {
  display: none !important;
}

div.menu__top:hover {
  right: 0;
}

div.menu__top:hover i{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="menu__top animation-flash">
  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>
  <div class="menu__top__content">
    <div class="menu__top__content--title">
      <span>Ссылки</span>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
    <a href="#" class="menu__top--link">Ссылка</a>
  </div>
</div>
```